# Universal Set Class - Copy Constructor

Tags: c++

Afternoon, guys and gals.

So I'm working on a universal set at the moment, trying to get my copy constructor to work. I have a node class finished. I'm at the point where everything seems to make sense to me, but it's still not working..

*Granted, I'm still having issues wrapping my head around linked lists.*

```
template<class T>
set<T>::set(const set<T> & other) {
    if(other.head == NULL) { head = NULL; }
    else {
        node <T> * s_ptr;
        node <T> * d_ptr;
        head = new node;
        head -> get_data() = other.head -> get_data();
        s_ptr = other.head -> set_link();
        d_ptr = head;

        while (s_ptr != NULL) {
            d_ptr -> set_link() = new node;
            d_ptr = d_ptr -> set_link();
            d_ptr -> data = s_ptr -> get_data();
            s_ptr = s_ptr -> link();
        } //end while

        d_ptr -> set_link() = NULL;     
    } //end else 
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help. You guys are awesome.

Edit:
This is the code to set the link:
`void set_link(node * n){link = n;}`

This is the code to get the data:
`T get_data(){return data;}`

Edit 2:
It's not compiling for me. On the lines that declare a `new node` I am getting the error:
`expected type specifier before node`
`expected ';' before node`

Am I missing a `<T>` somewhere?

Comment: Not working or not compiling? Give us compiler errors or runtime errors :)

Comment: Thanks - still getting used to the eitquette here :)

Comment: We can't help you unless you post the **actual** code. What you've pasted does not compile, and makes no sense in several ways, e.g. `d_ptr -> set_link() = new node;` doesn't match up with `void set_link(node * n){link = n;}`

Comment: I'm getting even more confused and flustered. I'm going to spend an hour with it and try to break down all my functions, and then I'll come back when I understand it more.  Thanks again, especially to Erik. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
head=new node<T>;
if(rhs.head!=NULL)
{
   node<T> *temp =new node<T>;
   node<T> *temp2=new node<T>;

   head->set_data(rhs.head->get_data());

   temp2=rhs.head->get_link();
   temp=head;

   while(temp2!=NULL)
   {
      temp->set_link(new node<T>);
      temp=temp->get_link();
      temp->set_data(temp2->get_data());
      temp2=temp2->get_link();
   }
}
else
{
  head==NULL;
}
```

You can't use functions as if they are variables.

Answer (score 1):

`d_ptr->link()` looks funny. Should be `d_ptr->link`. Same for a few other uses of `link`

EDIT: If `link` is a member function, how do you assign to it using e.g. `d_ptr -> link = new node;`

I think we need to see the node class - or you need to paste the correct code.

EDIT2: In response to the compiler error:

`new node;` should be `new node<T>;`

Comment: It's `link()` because we're using `node` as a seperate class...so `link()` is a function.

Comment: If "link" is a function, what is "link" without `()` doing in the code?

Comment: Please post **actual** code. What you've posted isn't going to compile.

Comment: Sorry, Erik. Thank you for being so patient with me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the line

```
d_ptr = d_ptr -> link();
```

supposed to do? At this point d_ptr is newly constructed, presumably with it's link NULL. The rest of it looks OK to me (except for the link vs link() noted by Erik).

Comment: d_ptr->link is newly constructed, not d_ptr. But there's something funny going on with the function/variable.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing i can think of is a problem with link if you call it as a function.
if link is realy a function and it has a prototype like `node* link()` then there is a problem but otherwise there is no problem with your code; 
also a code like this should work too

```
template <class T> class node
{



  node*& link()
  {
    return *this;
  }
}
```